# Flutter web update url/route base on state

Tags: flutter, dart, url, routes, flutter-web

I'm new in flutter and I just want to know if this scenario/feature is possible in flutter/flutter web. I want to update the url/route base on the state of the screen. For example, in **9gag.com**, there are buttons for **Hot**, **Trending**, and **Fresh**. Then, if I clicked the **Hot** button its url will be updated to **9gag.com/hot** and also its contents, the same goes for **Trending** and **Fresh** buttons. Is this possible in flutter/flutter web? If so, how do I implement this feature?(much better if the implementation uses bloc)

Comment: Try using `fluro` package it works pretty good for `flutter web` URL based routing 

https://github.com/lukepighetti/fluro#navigating

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible and is very easy to achieve just use url_launcher [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) on onpressed/ontap

Example: Add this code somewhere like in the beginning of your stateful management or at the end of your code

```
  _launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.io';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Call it somewhere like this

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: new Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
```

Now if you have some 9gag/hot button or container whatever you are going with just put that url and when user taps it, it will open that url. If you want to open it inside the app webview that's also possible but slightly different.

Comment: Can this implementation be possible for this scenario? For example in "HomePage()" (URL: "example.com"). there is a button "Hot" and when I clicked that button the URL will be updated to "example.com/hot" and the contents of "HomePage()" will also be updated/changed

Comment: Contents of homepage wont be visible when you will open to a new url like in the above example on the raised button when you will click it you will be navigated to new space/screen if you are using the opening url inside the app without leaving the app or  you get to your browser of your phone.

Comment: So the said scenario won't be possible in flutter web? What I really want is that if, for example, If I changed "example.com"(showing new posts in HomeScreen) to "example.com/hot" it will show hot posts in HomeScreen.

Comment: The scenario you are defining will work fine with url launcher perfectly even in flutter web the package supports web its totally up-to you whether you want to show the /hot posts in HomeScreen or on a new Screen lets say HotScreen you just have to navigate the page by calling the navigator and call the function inside the new screen if you want the user to get navigated to specifically a screen for /hot trends

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly It's pretty straightforward use the default way of navigation and routing.
I'm not sure with your approach like you have mentioned

> I want to update the url/route base on the state of the screen

and

> Then, if I clicked the Hot button its url will be updated to 9gag.com/hot and also its contents

If I'm not wrong there is a inbuilt feature of navigating to other screens and once you land on the desired screen, you can see the refreshed content. If you want to try material design the code will be like this

```
    //within your stateful or stateless widget
     onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPage()),
```

Instead of using a package you can try this inbuilt way of doing the same job. But it's upto you which one you want to use. Checkout the official flutter documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation
I hope this approach also helps to answer your question. If so happy to help in your flutter journey, if not share that how did you solved it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but what I want is that, for example in "HomePage()" (URL: "example.com"). there is a button "Hot" and when I clicked that button the URL will be updated to "example.com/hot" and the contents of "HomePage()" will also be updated/changed.